# Regular Pentagon is the Unique Largest Two-Distance Set in the Plane

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry

A **two-distance set** is a collection of points for which only two distinct distances appear among pairs of points. (That is, the distance between any pair of points is either $x$ or $y$, and these values may be whatever you want.)

The unique (up to similarity) largest two-distance set in the plane is the regular pentagon. The result seems to have become folklore, and I cannot find a proof anywhere online. I am primarily interested in the bound of five on the size of the two-distance set, but a proof of uniqueness would be a welcome bonus.

Comment: Very interesting: are there geometry related examples of $n$-distance sets?

Comment: @Avitus According to [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=WehCspo0Qa0C&pg=PA210#v=onepage&q&f=false), a few exact results are known. In the plane, for example, the largest $n$-distance set is known for $n \leq 6$. Incidentally, this reference mentions an old Monthly article by L. M. Kelly that supposedly contains the proof for a pentagon. I cannot seem to access this article as a mere mortal, however, so I thought it worth seeking an open solution here.

Comment: thanks for the nice reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is a two distance set of size $n=6$. Label each of the edges according to whether they have length $d_1 \neq d_2$. From Ramsey Theory, we know that a monochromatic triangle exists.

Let the 3 vertices of the monochromatic triangle be $A, B, C$, WLOG distance $d_1$. Now, consider the intersections of circles with radius $d_1$ and $d_2$ about centers $A$ and $B$, which have to give us the 3 other points.

If circles of radius $d_1$ intersect at a vertex that is not $C$, then we have $d_2 = \sqrt{3} d_1$.
If circles of $d_2$ intersect at a vertex, there are 2 possibilities for vertices. By considering the distance to $C$, we must have $ d_2 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} d_1$ or $ d_2 = 2 \frac{ \sqrt{3}}{3} d_1$.
Notice that all of these $d_2$ are different, and hence we can have at most 1 of these points as a vertex.

If circles of radius $d_1$ and $d_2$ intersect at a vertex that is on the different side of $AB$ as $C$, there are 4 possibilities of points, with 2 on either side of $AB$. However, the points on either side of $AB$ will result in different values of $AB$, hence we can have at most 2 of these points as a vertex.

Hence, we must have 1 from the first set of points, and 2 from the second set of points. However, it is easy to see that non of the distances from the first set, will result in valid points in the second set.

---

Uniqueness:

Suppose that we have a set of 5 points that are two-distance. Color each edge as before.

**Claim:** It doesn't contain a monochromatic triangle.

Suppose it does. Let the vertices be $A, B, C$, and the other 2 points be $D, E$. Take the circles with centers $A, B$. Then from the above, we know that the other 2 points must be from the 3 possible intersection points, so $C, D, E $ are collinear. The only 2-distance set of collinear points is where one of them is the midpoint of the other. By considering the possible positions, we must have (WLOG) $D$ as the other intersection of the cirlces that $C$ lies on. Then, (WLOG) $ED=DC =\sqrt{3} CA$ But $EA \neq CA, EA \neq CE$ hence we have a contradiction.

**Claim:** No monochromatic 4-cycle exists.

Suppose it does. Then, we must have a rhombus. Consider the lengths of the diagonals.
If they are distinct, then one of them is the side length of the rhombus, so we have a monochromatic triangle, contradicting the previous claim.
If they are equal and distinct from the side length of the rhombus, we have a square. It's quick to argue that no 5th point works.

From the above claims, the complete graph on 5 vertices must be formed from 2 5-cycles. Hence, we must have the regular pentagon.